# Moving items in listbox to its original position

Tags: c++, list, c#-4.0

I have successfully moved items from one list to another, but there is one display issue, when I move item back from `LIST2` to `LIST1`, then the item is positioned at the end, so I have scroll down to see if it is there or not.

How can I again make the `listitems` In `LIST1` sorted or how to add it back to its original position?

I have written the code in `.cs` file so no `jquery` or `javascript` is required as an option.
This my code to move items in between lists:

```
 if (SelectedInvestorsLst.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            string _value = SelectedInvestorsLst.SelectedItem.Value;
            string _text = SelectedInvestorsLst.SelectedItem.Text;
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = _text;
            item.Value = _value;
            InstitutionLst.Items.Add(item);
            SelectedInvestorsLst.Items.Remove(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the insert method

```
 InstitutionLst.Insert(0, Item);
```

Comment: insert method will insert as well as item will be retained in the list1 as well? I am not sure to use the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are already storing some value. To restore the position, you should add the position from which it is removed to the value. As you are already using the value use a comma separated list like ExistingValue,removed_index.

When you move the item from right to left, you can use the removed_index to Insert (look at Rachel Gallen reply) the item at the required location.